# getResources().getString returns strange value

Tags: android, string, hyperlink

In my app I put a certain link in `strings.xml` file and then I use it in the rest of the application. Here is the way I put in `strings.xml` file :

```
<string name="link">http://mylink/</string>
```

and here in how I get it in my activity :

```
String link = getResources().getString(R.string.link);
```

The problem is that this String returns sometimes not the value from strings file. I get often #ff666666 and that's strange. Why sometimes it works fine and sometimes not ?

Has anyone any idea about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: elaborate **'sometimes'** with related code examples.

Comment: if I uninstall the application and install it again, it is possible to have this problem. This happens sometimes, sometimes it runs fine, but sometimes the value is not well get from xml file, and in this case my application shows an alert, so I can not do anything.

Comment: From where are you calling getResources().getString(R.string.link)? Activity? Service?

Comment: Activity. in onCreate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `Clean` and `Build` again before running the project.

This is happening because some times new values are added in the `R.java` file that doesn't get updated, so you need to clean to force the `R.java` file to refresh and update itself.

Comment: try changing the Name of the `link` in your Strings file to `my_link` and now make a reference in your Java file, this will work

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine. Just now i checked with following lines. Make sure sure to clean your project and build it.

```
<string name="link">http://www.google.com</string>


String name = getResources().getString(R.string.link);
Log.e("Name is:",name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging into the particular method and inspect the value of R.string.link. Is it the same as you would see in the R.java file? Sometimes you get this problem when shifting around stuff in your resource files. "Project->Clean...->Clean all projects" in Eclipse usually solves it.